# Custom dialog not showing, just faded black background

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

Ok I've been trying to write a separate class for custom dialog with static function here is the code

```
class CustomDialog {
    companion object {
        fun create(context: Context, content: String) {
            context as Activity
            val inflater = context.layoutInflater
            val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_info, null)
            val infoDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context).create()
            view.dialog_content.text = content
            view.dialog_okButton.setOnClickListener {
                println("CLICKED")
                infoDialog.dismiss()
            }
            infoDialog.setContentView(view)

            infoDialog.show()
        }
    }
}
```

and the layout which I'm inflating is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/iranyekanregular"
        android:text="Some text"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialog_okButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/iranyekanregular"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:text="OK" />
</LinearLayout>
```

A simple textview a separator line and a button to dismiss the dialog.

but whenever I trigger the button to show the dialog it just shows the faded black screen and not the dialog itself.
If I use the `setView(view)` instead of `setContentView` it pretty much shows it self but as it is only the middle(content) part of the default dialog I see the background of the default dialog and still the dismiss button won't work. any help will be much appreciated. btw I've searched a lot with no luck.

Comment: it maybe due to the styles you are giving to your class. Try giving the dialog a different style and check if it works or not.

Comment: might be if you pass activity root layout in inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_info, null),  instead of null, It might work properly.

Comment: @Umair could you please elaborate? if by style you mean the background of the layout I've changed to solid color with no luck.

Comment: @ArmanMomeni no I meant like the second answer recommends you to use the theme. I meant to say that. Use your theme or the one android offers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is arising due to the fact that you are not giving it any style.

```
Use  infoDialog.setView(view)
```

And while creating dialogbox give a material theme style

```
val infoDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(ContextThemeWrapper(context,android.R.style.ThemeOverlay_Material_Dialog)).create()
```

and in the end

```
infoDialog.window.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
infoDialog.show()
```

Rest of your code is fine.

Comment: Ok This works, without the need to the Theme part, cause that wasn't needed.With `setView` I had ugly sharp corner backgrounds of default dialog, but with setting the background to transparent it's all gone.I dunno if it's the correct way to do it with `setView` cause the default dialog is still showing and I have setPositive, Negative and Netural options available which I should not have. I'm waiting a bit more if someone has any other/better solution otherwise yours solved mine and I'm gonna mark it then. Thanks

Comment: OK, but when you will add the theme part then those ugly sharp corner backgrounds of default dialog will be removed as well. And if you will not set it then the android will set the default styles.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the inflated view to the dialog.

```
class CustomDialog {
companion object {
    fun create(context: Context, content: String) {
        context as Activity
        val inflater = context.layoutInflater
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_info, null)
        val infoDialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        infoDialogBuilder.setView(view)
        val infoDialog = infoDialogBuilder.create()
        view.dialog_content.text = content
        view.dialog_okButton.setOnClickListener {
            println("CLICKED")
            infoDialog.dismiss()
        }
        infoDialog.setContentView(view)

        infoDialog.show()
    }
}
```

That is the missing line:

```
infoDialogBuilder.setView(view)
```